# text_area with onkeyup event sends ajax request and renders but view does not change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

In a Ruby on Rails app, I make a simple form (`form_for`) to submit text. But I would like to display the updated text in the same page so I use `remote: true` (to submit as Ajax). It works fine if I type in the text_area and click the submit button.

However, I would like to tweak a bit, I set the `onkeyup: 'submitIt()'` event to the text_area and define the `function submitIt()` below the form as JQuery ( `$('#form-id').submit()` ). This time the form submit after each key up, BUT it submits in [text/html] and no longer respond to action update.js.erb anymore. Though it does update the text because the action update in the controller works, it just does not respond to render the view the way I want. This completely defeats the purpose and I am very frustrated reading stackoverflow and ruby rails blogs, to no avail.

Does anyone have any suggestion?

My form:

```
<%= form_for @product, remote: true, html: {id: 'edit-form'} do |f| %>
<ul class="errors"> </ul>

<%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>
<%= f.label :price %>
<%= f.text_field :price, onkeyup: 'submitIt()' %>

<%= f.submit %>

<% end %>

<script>
function submitIt() {
    $("#edit-form").submit();
}
</script>
```

Now I change the script to this:

```
<script>
function submitIt() {
    let valuesToSubmit = $('#edit-form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $('#edit-form').attr('action'),
        data: valuesToSubmit,
        dataType: "JSON"
    }).success(function(json){
        console.log("success", json);
    });

}
</script>
```

When I type and look at the server, the request is Ajax (JSON), the product change is committed, and it renders the update.js.erb with 200OK, (it does not print out the success message to the console though). And nothing in the view changes. If I click the button Submit, then it goes through the same sequence (the server log is the same as I type in), but it actually changes the view. Why?

Here is the server log of my typing behavior:

```
Started PATCH "/products/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-20 11:23:59 +0100
Processing by ProductsController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "product"=>{"name"=>"Nintendo", "price"=>"203"}, "authenticity_token"=>"vKsD9PcUN0DPLoWn44sYHZ6Fo0iB32u5nXyEmEw/WrYfiUC4qpKxTHWupdT8iMzHF5ji4CbWwVh7FrkxNJMFKQ==", "id"=>"1"}
  Product Load (2.4ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:21
   (1.1ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:22
  Product Update (18.6ms)  UPDATE "products" SET "price" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "products"."id" = ?  [["price", 203.0], ["updated_at", "2019-01-20 10:23:59.220778"], ["id", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:22
   (105.2ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:22
  Rendering products/update.js.erb
  Product Load (10.1ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products"
  ↳ app/views/products/_index.html.erb:1
  Rendered products/_index.html.erb (134.5ms)
  Rendered products/update.js.erb (161.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 494ms (Views: 196.0ms | ActiveRecord: 137.5ms)
```

Here is the one where I click the button:

```
Started PATCH "/products/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-20 11:22:46 +0100
Processing by ProductsController#update as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "product"=>{"name"=>"Nintendo", "price"=>"20"}, "authenticity_token"=>"vKsD9PcUN0DPLoWn44sYHZ6Fo0iB32u5nXyEmEw/WrYfiUC4qpKxTHWupdT8iMzHF5ji4CbWwVh7FrkxNJMFKQ==", "commit"=>"Update Product", "id"=>"1"}
  Product Load (2.1ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:21
   (1.2ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:22
   (1.1ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:22
  Rendering products/update.js.erb
  Product Load (2.5ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products"
  ↳ app/views/products/_index.html.erb:1
  Rendered products/_index.html.erb (135.0ms)
  Rendered products/update.js.erb (161.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 321ms (Views: 197.0ms | ActiveRecord: 6.8ms)
```

They are the same.

Now I make a draft app to check, the submit button works for creating new product but does not render the correct view for the update action. Very strange. The only different in the server log is PATCH and POST request.

Gemfile:

```
...
ruby '2.5.1'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
...
```

I add this into `application.js`

```
//= require jquery
```

Comment: What version of rails are you using?

Comment: ```rails 5.2.2``` can it be a conflict between gems like jquery-rails, etc? I make another draft app to check, and now the submit button suffers the same problem. it clicks, the params is sent, it looks for the correct response *.js.erb and it says ```rendered``` but the view does not change (though the product in the database is updated successfully.

Comment: Check in your project if you are using rails-ujs or jquery-ujs?

Comment: i added this ```gem 'jquery-rails'``` into Gemfile otherwise jquery would not load. because of that gem i put ```//= require jquery``` into ```application.js```. if i add ```jquery-ujs``` into ```application.js``` it would says that it is redundant because the ```application.js``` already has ```rails-ujs```. so i'm using ```rails-ujs```

Comment: Check this https://gorails.com/forum/do-i-need-rails-ujs-and-jquery_ujs

Comment: it says ```rails-ujs``` replaces ```jquery-ujs```. but i do that. i don't add ```jquery-ujs```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that rails-ujs triggers the submit different, so a solution could be to trigger the default behavior https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29546#issuecomment-313572043

```
<script>
function submitIt() {
   var editForm = $("#edit-form")[0];
   Rails.fire(editForm, 'submit');
}
</script>
```